# Laravel json type array validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want validate all data.
I can't do that, `educations` `language` i send `JSON string array`

I try:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        "name" => "required|max:255",
        "email" => "required|max:255",
        "district_id" => "required|max:11",
        "division_id" => "required|max:11",
        "upazila_id" => "required|max:11",
        "address_details" => "required|max:255",
        "training" => "required",
        "languages" => "required|array",
        "educations" => "required|array",
        "educations.*.exam_name" => "required|max:255",
        "educations.*.university_name" => "required|max:255",
        "educations.*.board_name" => "required|max:255",
        "educations.*.result" => "required",
        "photo" => "required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048",
        "cv" => "required|file|mimes:doc,pdf,docx|max:2048",
        "training" => "required",
        "trainings.*.name" => 'required_if:training,Yes',
        "trainings.*.description" => 'required_if:training,Yes'
    ]);
```

Axios post:

```
let fd = new FormData();
  Object.keys(this.application).map((key,value) =>{
    if(key === 'photo' || key == 'cv')
      fd.append(key, this.application[key]);
    else
      fd.append(key, JSON.stringify(this.application[key])); 
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try json decoding before you run the validator, like:

```
$request->replace([
    'educations' => json_decode($request->educations, true),
    'languages' => json_decode($request->languages, true),
]);

$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    "name" => "required|max:255",
    "email" => "required|max:255",
    "district_id" => "required|max:11",
    "division_id" => "required|max:11",
    "upazila_id" => "required|max:11",
    "address_details" => "required|max:255",
    "training" => "required",
    "languages" => "required|array",
    "educations" => "required|array",
    "educations.*.exam_name" => "required|max:255",
    "educations.*.university_name" => "required|max:255",
    "educations.*.board_name" => "required|max:255",
    "educations.*.result" => "required",
    "photo" => "required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048",
    "cv" => "required|file|mimes:doc,pdf,docx|max:2048",
    "training" => "required",
    "trainings.*.name" => 'required_if:training,Yes',
    "trainings.*.description" => 'required_if:training,Yes'
]);
```

Comment: now `educations` & `language` work other like `name`  `email` say required but I put data

Comment: what you mean by `say required but I put data`

Comment: other columns Like  `name`  `email` data remove from request->all()

Comment: you are not removing the data actually, you are just replacing it

Comment: but only show `educations` & `languages` data . other data not showing

Comment: can you try `$request->merge` instead of `$request->replace`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229245/discussion-between-brahim-dogan-and-hasan-sheikh).